# Methanol mixed with varsol

Tags: solubility, solvents

If I have varsol in a tank and methanol is put into the same tank will methanol rise to the top or will it separate? Or will it mix together ?

Comment: please give a citation for Varsol, this is not a well-known material

Answer (score 3):

Note that I have never heard about Varsol until now, living in the Central Europe. By searching Wikipedia ( what you could do as well before asking ), I realized the below:

[Varsol alias White spirit alias many other synonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_spirit?wprov=sfla1), used as a painting solvent, is based on C7-C12 oil hydrocarbons, with density 0.765(type T1), 0.780(type T2), 0.795(type T3)
( divided by volatility, T1 the most volatile )

[Methanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanol?wprov=sfla1) has density 0.792. So it would rather sink under T1, T2, or being indecisive with T3 ( this may be temperature dependent )

Note that methanol has very limited solubility in non-aromatic hydrocarbons.

Note: with reported partial aromaticity, methanol will be somewhat soluble.

Answer (score 2):

Poutnik has given an excellent answer in general for your question. Since you asked about Varsol™ in particular (not white spirit in general), I'd like to give an additional insights for your benefit. Yet you didn't mention the paticular Varsol™ brand so I'll give physical data for all 3 Varsol™ brands avilable.

Varsol™ is an ExxonMobil Chemical brand for a line of conventional *non-dearomatized* aliphatic fluids boiling in the mineral spirit or white spirits range. ExxonMobil offers several Varsol™ brands, namely, Varsol™ 1 (distillation range: $\pu{156-204 ^\circ C}$), Varsol™ 18 (distillation range: $\pu{159-203 ^\circ C}$), and Varsol™ 110 (distillation range: $\pu{249-294 ^\circ C}$). Varsol™ is an aliphatic fluids, but is *non-dearomatized*. Their aromatic content ($wt \%$) could go as high as 29% depending on the brand. I have no experience with Varsol™, thus, I can only speculate that any Varsol™ brand's solubility level in methanol can be depend on their aromatic content values. For example, toluene and xylenes are missible in methanol but hexanes and heptane are not. However, since aromatic content is less than 50%, I can assure that there would be two immersible layers, assuming you are adding equal amount of methanol (based on the amount of methanol you are adding). In that case, which layer be on top can depend on which brand of Varsol™ you are using: Densities of Varsol™ 1, 18, and 110 are $0.789, 0.790$, and $\pu{0.825 gcm-3}$, respectively at $\pu{15.6 ^\circ C}$. According to the values given by Poutnik, Varsol™ 1 and 18 would be the upper layer while Varsol™ 110 would sink to the bottom when you add enough methanol to the brand of Varsol™ in your tank.

**Source:** [Fluids at a glance - ExxonMobil Chemical](http://Fluids%20at%20a%20glance%20-%20ExxonMobil%20Chemical)